# Fighting Rails CRUD on one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a slightly unusual edit component in my rails 3.0 applucation which contains a record selector at the top of the page, and the edit form on the second half of the page, which is turning out to be more difficult than I expected.

The record selector at the top gives you a list of records in a list box and a submit  button which calls the edit method in the controller which does a find on the record ID and returns the index page.

```
before_filter :load

def index
end

def edit
  render :action => "index"  
end


def update
  if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated project."
  end

  render :action => 'index'
end

def load
  @projects = Project.order("name asc")
  unless params[:id].nil?
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  else
    @project = Project.new
  end
end
```

As you can see from the above code, I don't want to leave the index page at any point.

So far this is working, I can select a project, edit the info, and click save.

Unfortunately when update is called and renders the index page, it isn't giving the params[:id] back to the index method, so the form goes blank, i.e. it doesn't remember what project you were editing.

I would like it to persist this project, so you can either make further changes, or select a different project up the top of the page.

I'm not sure how to go about htis, or if I'm approaching this component entirely wrong.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in the `index.html.erb`, you're using of one the [select helper method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html). These methods have various may to define the selected element, look at the doc for the method you're using. If needed, use a class instance variable in the `update` method to set the id to select, and use it in `index.html.erb`.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately when update is called and renders the index page, it isn't giving the params[:id] back to the index method, so the form goes blank, i.e. it doesn't remember what project you were editing.

So you're updating `@project`. And you're calling `render`. So when rendering `index`, `@project` is either a new project (if `params[:id]` is not set) or an existing one. But that about the `@project` you had in your `update`? You just need to keep that and not overwrite it with `Project.new` if `params[:id]` is blank. Why not change the load filter to e.g. this? (untested)

```
def load
    @projects = Project.order("name asc")

    unless @project
        unless params[:id].nil?
            @project = Project.find(params[:id])
        else
            @project = Project.new
        end
    end
end
```

If you really want to rely on `params[:id]`, you could replace your `render` to something like `redirect_to projects_path(:id => @project.id)` but then you're missing the error informations in your project object, which you may display.